# Book trilogy about a girl traveling in different worlds

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this trilogy when I was a kid in about 2010. The titles of the book all contain animals.

The first book has a plot where the girl have to steal something important from a vault, and the vault is actually a toad/frog who has the treasure inside its stomach.

The second one is about her traveling into a giant building, where each level is a separated world, and people cannot travel from one to another, but the girl had to do so.

The other book talks about another planet where there are dragons living in the sea. The dragons are eating the continental plates, making lands into islands floating above the sea, and the girl went inside the dragon's body to kill it.

That is all I can remember about this trilogy, could someone please help me recall its name?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.